# ODE with renderscript android

Tags: android, ode, renderscript, android-renderscript

I want to use neural networks with renderscript. i want to know if there is a way to solve an ODE (ordinary differential equation) with renderscript. is there anything specific for ODEs with BLAS new intrinsic android have provided?